# Angular: How to make get request after post/put request is successful?

Tags: angular, xmlhttprequest

I got device list using `get request`. I edited some details and updated it using `put request` but now I want that my list should update(make get request) after successful `put request`.

here is what I am trying:

```
putConfig(Device) {

    var request =  this._http
        .put(this._puturl+Device.deviceId, Device)
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(res => this.getConfig() )



    return request;
}
```

It does't look this work. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you return is actually a subscription, what you need to do is:

```
var request = this._http
  .put(...)
  .switchMap(() => this.getConfig());

return request;
```

Make sure you subscribe to the result:

```
putConfig(Device).subscribe()
```

To make it 'hot', otherwise it will not trigger.

Note that I removed the map operation since it is not required, you do not use the `res` anyways.

Comment: It says `'switchMap' does not exist on type 'Observable<Response>'.`!

Comment: You should import it: `import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';`